# UNIX: Getting count occurance of numbers from a CSV file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a `CSV` file with first column & second column as `ID`,`domain`.

```
#Input.txt
1,google.com
1,cnn.com
1,dropbox.com
2,bbc.com
3,twitter.com
3,hello.com
3,example.com
4,twitter.com
.............
```

Now, I would like to get the count of `IDs`. Yes,this can be done in Excel/sheets but the file contains of about 1.5Million lines.

```
Expected Output: 
1,3
2,1
3,3
4,1
```

I tried using  `cat Input.txt | grep -c 1` and that which gives me count of '1' as `3` but I would like to do it for individual `ID` count all at once. Can any one help me on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Is the input file sorted?

Comment: `awk -F, '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file` or `cut -d, -f1 file | sort | uniq -c | rev`

Comment: @user000001 Yes,The file is sorted.

Comment: @123 Got it.Thanks mate !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F "," '{ ids[$1]++} END { for(id in ids) { print id, ids[id] } }' input
```

And input is the file with the data.

output:

```
1 3
2 1
3 3
4 1
```

Edit://
If you want a comma seperated output you need to set the output seperator like this:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN { OFS=","} { ids[$1]++} END { for(id in ids) { print id, ids[id] } }' input
```

output:

```
1,3
2,1
3,3
4,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, though the count is present in the 1. column:

```
$ zcat Input.txt.gz | cut -d , -f 1 | sort | uniq -c
      3 1
      1 2
      3 3
      1 4
```

Here's another way using awk:

```
$ awk -F , '{counter[$1]++}; 
  END {for (id in counter) printf "%s,%d\n",id,counter[id];}' Input.txt | 
  sort
1,3
2,1
3,3
4,1
```

Comment: @123 You can do this in a 100 different ways, sure.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that using cat is pointless and adds nothing to the command.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job in `bash`:

```
$ for i in {1..4}; do echo -n $i, >> OUTPUT && grep -c $i Input.txt >> OUTPUT; done
$ less OUTPUT
1,3
2,1
3,3
4,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, '{ print $1 }' input.txt | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 "," $1 }'
1,3
2,1
3,3
4,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure awk solution. It doesn't map the entire file in memory, so it will probably use less memory that @Joda's answer, but it assumes that the file is sorted:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$1==prev{c++;next}{print prev,c; c=1}{prev=$1}END{print prev,c}' file
```